# prolog-false is returned instead of a number

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a predicate that returns the minimum and maximum between two numbers.
The `min` and `max` predicates work fine, however when I try the `min_max` function with for example `min_max(2,5,X,Y)`, I get false.
Can anyone help?

```
min(X,Y,X) :- X=<Y.
min(X,Y,Y) :- Y<X.

max(X,Y,Y) :- X=<Y.
max(X,Y,X) :- Y<X.

min_max(X,Y,MIN,MAX) :-
   min(X,Y,MIN),
   max(X,Y,MAX).
```

Comment: In the latest SWI-Prolog: `?- min_max(2,5,X,Y). X = 2, Y = 5`.

Comment: @false Not that I know of. I merely wanted to indicate that on my implementation of Prolog I cannot reproduce the reported behavior (i.e., the goal not succeeding).

Answer (score 1):

Your `min/2` and `max/2` are *indeterminate*, so there are alternatives to be looked for. When you evaluate

```
min_max(2,5,X,Y).
```

You see

```
X = 2,
Y = 5
```

and it pauses, waiting for input from you. If you then press `.`, it will succeed. If, however, you press `;` it searches for the alternatives, and finding none, fails.

You need to modify your `min/2` and`max/2` to be *determinate*, something like this:

```
min(X,Y,Z) :- ( X < Y -> Z = X ; Z = Y ) .

max(X,Y,Z) :- ( X > Y -> Z = X ; Z = Y ) .
```

[The `->` operator (implication) effectively acts as a 'soft cut', eliminating alternatives.]

Once you do that, it will work as you might expect, without pausing for your input (as you've eliminated the choice points):

```
13 ?- min_max(2,5,X,Y).
X = 2,
Y = 5.

14 ?-
```

It might help if you think of the your prolog program as something of a tree with the choice points as branches (and solutions as leaf nodes). The prolog engine runs over that tree trying to find solutions.

In your original program, your `min_max/4` has 4 *possible* solutions (2 for `min/2` and 2 for `max/2`), even though there is just one "functional" solution. On backtracking, the prolog engine trys to find alternative solutions and finding none, fails.

By re-writing `min/2` and `max/2` to eliminate the choice points, we are effectively pruning the tree as we descend it, leaving us with a single solution.

Comment: Your statement "The `->` operator ... a 'soft cut' ..." is misleading. I get what you want to express, but 'soft cuts' are already in SWI (`(*->)/3`) and SICStus (`if/3`). Unlike `->` the soft cuts do not eliminate alternatives.

Comment: @repeat: There is no `(*->)/3`, it's rather `(;)/2` since the principal functor is `(;)/2` and not `(*->)/2`.

Answer (score 1):

How about combining `min/3` and `max/3` in a slightly different way?
Consider this definition:

```
min_max(X,Y,X,Y) :- X =< Y.
min_max(X,Y,Y,X) :- Y  < X.
```

Sample queries:

```
?- min_max(2,5,Min,Max).
Min = 2,  Max = 5 ;
false.

?- min_max(20,5,Min,Max).
Min = 5,  Max = 20.

?- min_max(10,10,Min,Max).
Min = 10, Max = 10 ;
false.
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it (+1): if you have a min, the other one should be max (right?); I don't like the dangling choice points, but I don't want to get into that topic.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29156560/sorting-large-lists-in-prolog-not-enough-memory/29164060#29164060) somewhere in the middle is a discussion on how to avoid the choice point. Spurious choice points are the one truly ugly face of Prolog (personal opinion, arguments: gut feeling).

Comment: @Boris: Spurious choice points are an efficiency problem, but they do not affect correctness. Better programming techniques (like [`if_/3`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/772868) and [`call_semidet/1`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12942551/772868)) can help to remove them.

Comment: Please note the asymmetry of this definition when you consider floats, too. Like `min_max(1,1.0, Min, Max)` and `min_max(1.0,1,Min,Max)`.